# JoGL: rendering a point, parameters

Tags: opengl, parameters, rendering, point

I need to give the user the possibility to insert some custom geometry, like a point.

He can specify size and color.

Trying to get how the different parameters work, I got these values on my platform:

GL_POINT_SIZE_MIN: 33062

GL_POINT_SIZE_MAX: 33063

> GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE and GL_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY are deprecated in GL
> versions 1.2 and greater. Their functionality has been replaced by
> GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE and GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY.

GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE: 2834

GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY: 2835

Could somebody explain to me these strange values? I mean, how can differ the min and max values by just one?

The values above are taken in the following way:

```
System.out.println("max: "+GL2.GL_POINT_SIZE_MAX+" min: "+GL2.GL_POINT_SIZE_MIN);
System.out.println("range: "+GL2.GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE+" granularity: "+GL2.GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY);
```

On the suggestions of datenwolf and Denis Germ I am now retriving parameters as follows:

```
float ps[] = new float[5];

gl2.glGetFloatv(GL2.GL_POINT_SIZE_MIN, ps, 0);
gl2.glGetFloatv(GL2.GL_POINT_SIZE_MAX, ps, 1);
gl2.glGetFloatv(GL2.GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, ps, 2);
gl2.glGetFloatv(GL2.GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY, ps,4);
        
System.out.println("min: "+ps[0]+" max: "+ps[1]);
System.out.println("range: "+ps[2]+" - "+ps[3]+" granularity: "+ps[4]);
```

And now I get:

> min: 0.0 max: 63.375
>
> range: 1.0 - 63.375 granularity: 0.125

It looks better, but still, if range starts from 1.0, why min is 0.0f?

Comment: It looks like you put signed integers into unsigned variables. The point size values look like opposite ends of a 2-complement value range.

Comment: GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE gives you **two** values, not one.  `float val[] = new float[2];
 gl.glGetFloatv( GL.GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, val, 0  );
 System.out.println("min="+val[0]+" max="+val[1]);` [Take a look at this](http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/pointSize.html)

Comment: You printed out the max and min backwards. Check your `ps` indices again.

Comment: @DenisGerm How does it look now?

Comment: It looks weird... but you know what? I've got the same values Oo Tested it with C# and OpenTk, this is what i got: [Click for Image](http://dl.gameworx.org/images/glpointsize.png). Maybe min/max and range differing because of the deprecation of min/max.. i could not find anything on google =/ But maybe, it is as it is - set pointsize to 1.0f to 63.375f in 0.125f steps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE: glGet will return two values, where the first is the minimum and the secound is the maximum point size (range from min to max).

GL_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY: glGet will return a single value, which describes the granularity, for example, 0.1: you can specify point sizes as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, but not 1.05, 1.15, etc.

Comment: Ok, but look at the values I got, how would you explain them?

Comment: From where did you get them? Are they described as `#define GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE 0x0B12` ? Then, they are probably defined parameters, to call the glGet functions: [http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml)

Comment: The point sizes aren't definied by the specification but by the graphics card - an NVidia GT540 might have other point sizes then an ATI or Intel or even another NVidia graphics card. Simply type `float ps[2]; glGetFloatv(GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, ps); std::cout<<"Min: "<<ps[0]<<", Max: "<<ps[1]<<"\n";` (Not testet, should be correct)